# How to show filed in distinct codeigniter

Tags: distinct, codeigniter-3

Hello guys I would like to distinct field `product_code` and I would like to show all field 
Table Transaction :

```
---------------------------------------------------
| id | product_code | price | datetime            |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 001          |20     | 2018-18-12 09:09:09 |
| 2  | 002          |30     | 2018-18-12 08:09:09 |
| 3  | 001          |20     | 2018-18-12 08:08:08 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

This is my model :

```
$this->db->distinct('product_code');
$this->db->select('id','product_code','price','datetime');
$this->db->from($this->table);
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution for you problem :

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('id','product_code','price','datetime');
$this->db->from($this->table);
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Than

```
echo $query->num_rows();
```

OR

```
$this->db->select('DISTINCT(product_code), ');  
$this->db->from($this->table);  
$query=$this->db->get();  

print_r($this->db->get()->result_array());

echo $query->num_rows();exit;
```

I hope it will help you.